# with pdo library using namespace

Tags: php, pdo

Everything works fine as long as I have not added namespace. Befor PDO i add /, but stil PDO object is empty, why? Whats wrong with my code?

Full sampe:

```
<?php
namespace ProjectM;

class classPDO extends DbCore
{
    public function get()
    {               
        $this->dbLink = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test_db', 'root', 'pass1312');

        print_r($this->dbLink); // - always empty

        $res = $this->dbLink('SELECT * FROM product')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  

        print_r($res); // - always empty
    }
```

Error: Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Core\classPDO::dbLink()

Why "$this->dbLink" is empty? Thanks

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962789/get-results-from-from-mysql-using-pdo/13962863#13962863

Comment: `new \PDO` -> `new PDO`

Answer (score 0):

Your `new \PDO` instantiation is correct. Your property `->dbLink` gets created alright. But the PDO instance does not implement `__call`. Thus this won't work:

```
$res = $this->dbLink('SELECT ...')
```

You still need to follow the API of the PDO class.
In your case, use the `->query` method after referencing your PDO instance property:

```
$res = $this->dbLink->query('SELECT ...')
```