# Having trouble fetching results from a MySQL table with PDO

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a simple login system. What I'm having trouble with is fetching the password hash from the database.

This is what I have:

```
$statement = 'SELECT Pass FROM Emails WHERE Email = "?"';
$question = array($email);
    try {
        $DB->beginTransaction();
        $preparedStatement = $DB->prepare($statement);
        $preparedStatement->execute($question);
        $resultArr = $preparedStatement->fetchAll();
        print_r($resultArr);
        $DB->commit();
    } catch(\PDOException $ex) {
        echo "Seriously bad error. ";
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
```

My problem is that `$resultArr` always contains no elements.

I know the SQL query itself works, as I've tested it directly in MySQL.

I believe that I have to use a prepared statement, as I'm sending user input to MySQL and have to defend against easy SQL injection attacks.

I'm using `fetchAll()` in order to make sure that there's only one result for a given email. Otherwise, there will be a huge problem.

What is my mistake here?

Comment: Why is `$question = array($email);`? Why not just `$question = $email;`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get results from from MySQL using PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962789/get-results-from-from-mysql-using-pdo)

Comment: remove double quotes around ?

Answer (score -1):

Just for sake of cleaning this extremely superfluous code

```
$stmt = $DB->prepare('SELECT Pass FROM Emails WHERE Email = ?');
$stmt->execute(array($email));
$pass = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

these 3 lines is ALL you need to run a query and get result.

And yes, the problem is just quotes around ? mark.

To ensure there is no other email you ought to use unique index in Mysql

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = 'SELECT Pass FROM Emails WHERE Email = :email';
    try {
        $DB->beginTransaction();
        $preparedStatement = $DB->prepare($query);
        $preparedStatement->bindParam("email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $preparedStatement->execute();
        $resultArr = $preparedStatement->fetchAll();
        print_r($resultArr);
        $DB->commit();
    } catch(\PDOException $ex) {
        echo "Seriously bad error. ";
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
```