# Binding result of a query with PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this simple query that finds the average salary of a table named permanent_employee:

```
SELECT  AVG(E.salary) 
FROM employee as E,permanent_employee as P
WHERE E.empID=P.empID
```

What i want to to is bind this to a PHP variable.If this returned the salary i would bind it like this `echo "<td>{salary}</td>";` and everything would work OK.However this `echo "<td>{$AVG(E.salary)}</td>";`  gives me errors.How could i make this query return a variable that can be later coverted to PHP form?

UPDATE:
solution was to use AVG(E.salary) AS sth

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT  AVG(E.salary) as salary`?

Comment: Well, you need to actually write some PHP code that executes the query and fetches the result to start with.  Do you have any of that?  Or just the query itself?

Comment: `gives me errors`? What error(s) do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  a proper alias

```
SELECT  AVG(E.salary)  my_avg 
FROM employee as E,permanent_employee as P
WHERE E.empID=P.empID


echo "<td>{$my_avg}</td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can extract this to a php variable

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT  AVG(E.salary)  my_avg 
FROM employee as E,permanent_employee as P
WHERE E.empID=P.empID");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
$avg = $row['my_avg'];
echo "<td>".$avg."</td>";
```

You can also use PDO, see [Get results from from MySQL using PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962789/get-results-from-from-mysql-using-pdo)